# CTP protocol in Castalia OMNET++

Tags: makefile, omnet++, ctp

I get this error when I `make` Castalia-3.2 with CTP `https://code.google.com/p/ctp-castalia/`. I have omnetpp-4.6.

Command - `omnetpp` is working fine. I am able to run sample examples like dyna.

Castalia-3.2 is also working fine when CTP is not integrated.

When I integrate CTP, Castalia - `make` gives the error(mentioned at last).

I followed the Readme.txt provided with CTP protocol.

```
1) Copy CtpTest in CASTALIA_HOME/Simulations
2) Copy ctpTestingApplication CASTALIA_HOME/src/node/application/
3) Copy ctpNoe in CASTALIA_HOME/src/node/communication/routing/
4) Copy cc2420Mac in CASTALIA_HOME/src/node/communication/mac/
5) make clean
6) ./makemake
7) make
```

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong ?

```
  In file included from src/node/communication/mac/cc2420Mac/CC2420Mac.h:108:0,
             from src/node/communication/mac/cc2420Mac/CC2420Mac.cc:104:
    src/node/communication/mac/cc2420Mac/TosEnvironment.h:11:17: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef uint8_t error_t’
      typedef uint8_t error_t;
             ^
     In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/cerrno:41:0,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ext/string_conversions.h:44,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2815,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:52,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.8/stdexcept:39,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.8/array:38,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.8/tuple:39,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_map.h:63,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.8/map:61,
             from src/node/communication/mac/VirtualMac.h:19,
             from src/node/communication/mac/cc2420Mac/CC2420Mac.h:106,
             from src/node/communication/mac/cc2420Mac/CC2420Mac.cc:104:
 /usr/include/errno.h:68:13: error: ‘error_t’ has a previous declaration as ‘typedef int error_t’
 typedef int error_t;
         ^
In file included from /usr/include/asm-generic/errno.h:4:0,
             from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/errno.h:1,
             from /usr/include/linux/errno.h:1,
             from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/errno.h:24,
             from /usr/include/errno.h:35,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.8/cerrno:41,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ext/string_conversions.h:44,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2815,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:52,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.8/stdexcept:39,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.8/array:38,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.8/tuple:39,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_map.h:63,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.8/map:61,
             from src/node/communication/mac/VirtualMac.h:19,
             from src/node/communication/mac/cc2420Mac/CC2420Mac.h:106,
             from src/node/communication/mac/cc2420Mac/CC2420Mac.cc:104:

src/node/communication/mac/cc2420Mac/TosEnvironment.h:23:5: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
 EBUSY = 3,
 ^
  src/node/communication/mac/cc2420Mac/TosEnvironment.h:23:5: error:     expected ‘}’ before numeric constant

 src/node/communication/mac/cc2420Mac/TosEnvironment.h:23:5: error:    expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
 In file included from src/node/communication/mac/cc2420Mac/CC2420Mac.h:108:0,
             from src/node/communication/mac/cc2420Mac/CC2420Mac.cc:104:

src/node/communication/mac/cc2420Mac/TosEnvironment.h:28:1: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token

};
^
```

Comment: please post the code snippets for the files and lines where the compiler complains. The errors you get are compile-time errors related to declaration and initialization. But it is hard to tell without the snippets there...

Comment: Hi, I haven't made any changes to the code. It's the exact code obtained on downloading CTP from https://code.google.com/p/ctp-castalia/

Comment: sure, but you should place code snippets into the question so they are accessible for the others... and by pure common sense: no one will bother to check the code for you if you didn't bother to add it yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/ctp-castalia/issues/list?can=1&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&cells=tiles) on the website has some issues which have been solved already, related to `make`.

One of the fixes suggests the following:

> - in `CtpTestingApplication.cc` and `CtpTestingApplication.h`
> - replace `ApplicationGenericDataPacket` with `ApplicationPacket` in `CtpTestingApplication.cc`
> - comment out the whole `update_packets_received()` method
> - delete   `declareOutput("My Stats", SN) ;` from the `update_ddr_perSN()` method   and put `declareOutput("My Stats") ;`  at the `startup()` method
> - in `mac/cc2420Mac/CC2420Mac.cc`
> - replace instances of `getRoutingInteractionControl()` with `getNetMacInfoExchange()`
> - replace `getMacInteractionControl()` with `getMacRadioInfoExchange()`
> - swap RSSI with LQI in the right hand side of the assignments (little bug in the original code)
>
> Optional, depends on platform (I had to do it for my Mac OSX)
>
> - in `mac/cc2420Mac/TosEnvironment.h`  AND in `routing/ctpNoe/components/TosEnvironment.h:79` line 79 replace
>     `0x100000000` with `0xffffffff`
> - in `routing/ctpNoe/components/CtpForwardingEngine.cc`
> - replace line 1080 `netPkt->getNetMacInfoExchange().source = selfAddress.c_str() ;` // ok   with
>     `netPkt->setSource(selfAddress.c_str()) ;` // ok
> - replace instances of `getRoutingInteractionControl()` with `getNetMacInfoExchange()`   (lines 213, 1053, 1081)
> - in `routing/ctpNoe/components/CtpRoutingEngine.cc`  AND `routing/ctpNoe/components/DualBuffer.cc` AND
>     `routing/ctpNoe/components/LinkEstimator.cc`
> - replace instances of `getRoutingInteractionControl()` with `getNetMacInfoExchange()`

PS: maybe the problems are introduced due to using OMNET 4.6. A lower version (4.2) might work better with `Castalia`